# Stringify не сохраняет поля объекта

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const json = {
  features: [{
    properties: 1
  }]
}

json.features.newConfirmedMax = '0';
json.features.newDeathsMax = '0';
json.features.newRecoveredMax = '0';
json.features.totalConfirmedMax = '0';
json.features.totalDeathsMax = '0';
json.features.totalRecoveredMax = '0';
json.features.newConfirmedPer100Max = 0;
json.features.newDeathsPer100Max = 0;
json.features.newRecoveredPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalConfirmedPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalDeathsPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalRecoveredPer100Max = 0;
console.log(json.features.totalDeathsMax)
const out = JSON.stringify(json);
const test = JSON.parse(out);
console.log(test.features.totalDeathsMax);
```

проблема следующая, хочу добавить некоторые поля в json и после сохранить его в файл.

```
const json = {
  features: [
    {properties: 1}
  ]
}

json.features.newConfirmedMax = '0';
json.features.newDeathsMax = '0';
json.features.newRecoveredMax = '0';
json.features.totalConfirmedMax = '0';
json.features.totalDeathsMax = '0';
json.features.totalRecoveredMax = '0';
json.features.newConfirmedPer100Max = 0;
json.features.newDeathsPer100Max = 0;
json.features.newRecoveredPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalConfirmedPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalDeathsPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalRecoveredPer100Max = 0;
console.log(json.features.totalDeathsMax)
const out = JSON.stringify(json);
const test = JSON.parse(out);
console.log(test.features)
```

После Stringify эти поля пропадают, подскажите пожалуйста, почему?

Я понял, что feаtures - это массив, к сожалению, структуру я менять не могу, поскольку это формат geojson, может, можно как - то сделать, чтобы stringify не обрезал добавленные свойства?

Comment: с указанными данными, описанное поведение не возможно, попробуй сделать пример, который можно будет запустить и увидеть ошибку.

Comment: У вас `features` массив. У массивов `JSON.stringify` сохраняет только элементы массива (с индексами 0, 1 и т.д.) Замените его на объект

Answer (score 0):

Вот почему так

```js
const json = {features: [
    {properties: 1}
  ]};

json.features.newConfirmedMax = 0;
json.features.newDeathsMax = 1111;
json.features.newRecoveredMax = 0;
json.features.totalConfirmedMax = 0;
json.features.totalDeathsMax = 0;
json.features.totalRecoveredMax = 0;
json.features.newConfirmedPer100Max = 0;
json.features.newDeathsPer100Max = 0;
json.features.newRecoveredPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalConfirmedPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalDeathsPer100Max = 0;
json.features.totalRecoveredPer100Max = 0;
console.log("Вывод до stringify и повторного parse:",json.features.newDeathsMax)
console.log(json);
const out = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(out);
const test = JSON.parse(out);
console.log("Вывод после stringify и повторного parse:", test.features.newDeathsMax)
```

Comment: нет, я в коде просто показал, что totalDeathsMax теряется после stringify и parse

Comment: Ну тогда так посмотрите, и так всё в порядке

Comment: Добавил изменения в код

Comment: Потому что вы путаете понятия массива и объекта